# Overloading with params in C#

Tags: c#, .net, overloading

I have these two overloaded method definitions:

```
string[] Test1(string data)
```

and

```
string[] Test1(params string[] input)
```

When I call `Test1("Single test data")` with the intention of calling the second method, the first method gets called.

Why doesn't the compiler flag this scenario like it would for more obvious overload conflict scenarios?

Comment: Overload resolution in C# can be **complicated**, but in this case the first is the obviously better match ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯. If you expected this to call the 2nd option, the first wouldn't ever even be reachable.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why doesn't the compiler flag this scenario like it would for more obvious overload conflict scenarios?

Because the language rules tell it not to.

There's a very specific rule for this. From [section 12.6.4.3 of the C# 7 spec](https://github.com/dotnet/csharpstandard/blob/draft-v7/standard/expressions.md#12643-better-function-member):

> Otherwise, if Mᵢ is applicable in its normal form and Mₑ has a params array and is applicable only in its expanded form, then Mᵢ is better than Mₑ.

In this case, your first method is applicable in its normal form, and your second method is applicable only in its expanded form, therefore the first method is better than the second method.

Comment: Well I guess the question is why these rules were adopted in the first place?

Comment: @bashis: The rules describe what is wanted 99% of the time, I'd say. (In particular, if you expect `Test1("Single test data")` to call the second method, how would you *ever* expect to call the second method? It's easy to call the second method if you really want to - just construct a single-element array yourself.)

Comment: I do not expect this to call the second method, I would expect this to not compile as potentially ambiguous code. Maybe it's just me but having read Eric Lippert's blog I had a feeling that C# team was trying to prevent code that could be misinterpreted by the developer from compiling. This particular rule - though unambiguous for the compiler - clearly has potential for misinterpretation by the developer.

Comment: @bashis - *I would expect this to not compile as potentially ambiguous code.* -- code like this has been compiling successfully since .NET 1.1.  [`Console.WriteLine()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=netframework-1.1) has always had overloads for `WriteLine(String, Object)`, `WriteLine(String, Object, Object)` as well as `WriteLine(String, params Object[])` and there has never been any confusion.

Comment: @bashis: In what way is this "potentially ambiguous" while you're presumably happy with other overload resolution - e.g. between a `long` and an `int` parameter. It's not ambiguous when the C# language rules specify which overload will be chosen, which they've done since C# 1.0.

Comment: @dbc there has never been any confusion because these these overloads produce same results

Comment: @bashis: So overloads should be designed that way - it's not like the compiler says "Oh, it's `Console.WriteLine`, so I'll apply different language rules." Why would you expect the `Console.WriteLine` call to be ambiguous, but you'd expect *this* example to fail to compile?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by `long` and `int` overload resolution? Implicit casts? The same method having two overloads where one contains `long` as an arg and the other contains `int`? How is this similar?

Comment: @bashis: There's an implicit conversion from `int` to `long`, so any call to a method which is overloaded as `M(long x)` or `M(int x)` where the argument is an `int` is likewise "potentially ambiguous". (Both overloads would be applicable, so the compiler has to choose the "best" one.) I don't get any sense of what rules *you* would be proposing... (Fundamentally, your expectations *should* be set by the language specification - I've pointed out exactly why this code compiles the way it does, so IMO it would be best for you to reset your expectations.)

Answer (score 1):

The aim of `params` keyword is to allow you to give arbitrary number of parameters to the method.
I.e., "Single test data" is a SINGLE parameter, whereas the second overload only allows you to use an array object(s, arbitrary quantity of arrays) as the input.

You have to give it an array of strings to call the second overload:

```
using System;
class HelloWorld {
  static void Main() {
    Test1("one", "two", "three");
  }
  static string[] Test1(string data) {
    Console.WriteLine("First overload");
    return new string []{""};
  }
  
  static string[] Test1(params string[] input) {
      foreach (string str in input)
    Console.WriteLine(str);
    Console.WriteLine("Second overload");
    return new string []{""};
  }
}
```